# Sharepoint online->Settings wheel->Add an app not showing all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, custom-masterpage

One of the projects I am working on, I have a custom master page being used. Its basically a copy of seattle with some CSS and JS customization.

When I click on Add an app from the settings wheel, I only see the below options.

[image]

Even if i search for things like Calendar, Surveys, nothing comes up at all. When I switch the master page back to seattle then, it works fine, I don't see issues with it. So as of now , if i have to add a calendar, I have to switch the master page back to Seattle to make those options appear.

Can someone please help me resolve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Include following placeholder in your custom master page and set **Visible="true"**.

1. DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar.
2. PlaceHolderLeftNavBar.
3. DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea.
4. PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea.

check below code:

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Comment: Hi Anil, is there a specific place should I add these in the master page?

Comment: @mdevm, since these are independent placeholder you can add anywhere in master page just kake sure you put it inside the SharePointForm tag.

Answer (score 1):

Open Site Settings -> Site Features and activate "Team collaboration lists" 
You will now be able to see the following Apps

**Libraries**

Form Library,
Picture Library,
Document Library

**Lists**

Announcements,
Calendar,
Contacts,
Custom List,
Custom List with DataSheet View,
Discussion Board,
External List,
Issue Tracking List,
Links,
Project List,
Survey,
Tasks

If the feature is already activated then try deactivating and reactivating.

If that doesn't work please try creating a new site collection and see if it is working there.

The final step if all that fails is to raise a support ticket with microsoft, or alternatively you can provide the tenant details and site.

I have personally encountered this many times, and sometimes it required intervention with Microsoft for them to fix it from backend.

Comment: Hi James, its already activated.

Comment: Hi, please see updated answer, and upvote/mark if it assisted you.